# q(T) =0 implies q is a multiple of minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Sheldon Axler Linear Algebra Done Right Third Edition. On Page 264, there is a proof. I'm not understanding one of the equalities.

**Theorem:** Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $q \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$. Then $q(T) = 0$ if and only if $q$ is a polynomial multiple of the minimal polynomial of $T$.

**Proof:**
Let $p$ denote the minimal polynomial of $T$.
Suppose $q(T)=0$.
By the Division Algorithm for Polynomials, there eixsts polynomials $s,r \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$  such that $q=ps+r$ and degree $r$ < degree $s$.

We have $0 = q(T) =p(T)s(T) + r(T) = r(T)$.

The equation above implies that r=0 (otherwise, dividing $r$ by its highest degree coefficient would produce a monic polynomial that when applied to $T$ gives 0; this polynomial would have a smaller degree than the minimal polynomial, which would be a contradiction).

...

**My question is:**
How do we know that $p(T)s(T) + r(T) = r(T)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, we have $p(T)=0$ by definition, and hence $p(T)s(T)+r(T)=0+r(T)$.